# Core Plot slow on iPod Touch 2nd gen?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm using Core Plot to develop some iOS applications, but zooming and panning seems to be sort of slow and jerky on my iPod Touch 2nd gen (it looks fine in simulator). Is the device just slow? Should it look better on more recent iPhones and such? I can't get any of the examples to deploy to the iPod so I can't see how they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator uses the power of your computer to simulate the user interface and (a lot of) the software of an iOS device, not it's hardware. It is well possible the limited amount of memory and CPU of a second generation iPod Touch (not supported by the latest version of the OS for these reasons) can have issues with the heavy rendering made by Core Pot.  Latest devices do have more powerful gear, but are still way more constrained than your computer. If Core Plot s unusable on your device, it may still feel sluggish on other, more recent, devices because of a faulty implementation. Perhaps you could share with us some code of your integration or describe the type and quantity of data used by your app?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Well, my app is mostly designed to plot data in realtime (i.e. calling [graph reloadData] a lot) but it is also used to view static, unchanging graphs. Either way I use it, it seems to be similarly slow. The application itself is fairly large (about 2mb without many images or other custom content) but at the beginning, very little memory is allocated (the graph data array, the graph itself, the graphview, and a couple of small view controllers) and as more and more memory is allocated, the app doesn't seem to get much slower. So perhaps the processor?

Comment: I just successfully deployed one of the Core Plot examples to the iPod touch! (what a pain) it is also very slow... so it appears the device is the problem. Do you think newer devices would be significantly faster?

Comment: Indeed.  If you find one, try it out.  The cpu and gpu performance of A4 and A5 powered devices is particularly screaming, but even with a third generation iPod Touch or iPhone 3GS, you'd see a difference.